# BadImageFormatException in c#

Tags: c#, tesseract

I have downloaded tesseract from [Here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/downloads/detail?name=TesseractEngine3DotNetWrapper_RC2%20_r552.zip). When i tried to add the dll file to visual studio 2012, its showing error that its not an valid assembly. Can anyone suggest me some other dll file of ocr and sample coding. I've tried many websites but i dint found any good one. Then i found this [dll](http://tmp.m4f.eu/tessnet2.zip) file tessrect and used the following code

```
string path = @"C:\pic\mytext.jpg";
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path);
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
ocr.Init(@"C:\tessdata\", "eng", false); // To use correct tessdata
List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

But visual studio throwing error that its not valid assembly. can anyone help me in this ...
Edit : Error is

```
Could not load file or assembly 'tessnet2_64, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=1550524b5ba07e29' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Thanks n advance

Comment: Please post the *full* error message - and explain whether the error is at compile time or execution time. Ideally explain where you got the files from too, as it looks like you were going to include links but didn't...

Comment: @JonSkeet isnt this related to 32 bit vs 64 bit dlls?

Comment: @DarthVader: It might be, but it might not be. We don't really have enough information to tell right now.

Answer (score 3):

The most common reason I've seen for this error is that the .NET app was built as X86 and you are including an x64 assembly, or vice versa.

Check the configuration manager in visual studio (Build menu) and what the assembly expects.

**Update**

According to this forum post the DLL you are using is an x86 assembly: https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/issues/detail?id=16 (unless they've created an x64 version since then)

In that case set your application to x86. If you don't have this available as yet, go into the Configuration Manager (Build menu), and set the Platform to `x86`. If it's not in the menu you can either edit the existing entries or create a new one by selecting that option in the drop down. If you select new: In the dialog, select the New Platform as `x86` and copy the settings from what ever you were using currently.

Comment: Did you also change the active platform to "x86"?

Comment: yeah i've changed that too

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error occurred when I referenced a 32-bit project (DLL) in my 64-bit project.
It was necessary to change in the project configurations the target platform, to use preferably 32 bits:

Image:

[image: Photo]

When I checked the 32-bit preference, the problem was solved.

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, explain better how to fix it etc